# Regular Expression to Match Character and Max Length

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in javascript that will match these requirements

- Starts with a 0 but second digit not a 0
- 11-12 characters long
- Must contain exactly 1 space
- No other special characters or letters, just numbers

So far I have come up with 
`^[0][1-9][\d ]{9,10}$`

however, this would still match with 2 spaces or no spaces. I have been so far unsuccessful to find a way to require just one space anywhere within the number. I have tried positive lookahead and found other examples online, however making the quantifier work with the requirement has proven difficult.

Comment: Will the non-regex solution work for you?

Comment: It is being used in a HTML5 pattern attribute so needs to be a regex

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=.{11,12}$)(?=\S* \S*$)0[ 1-9][ \d]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA2gO9/1)

**Details:**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{11,12}$)` - total length must be 11 to 12 chars (just a lookahead check, fails the match if the condition is not met)
- `(?=\S* \S*$)` - there must be 1 space only (just a lookahead check, fails the match if the condition is not met)
- `0` - the first char *matched* must be `0`
- `[ 1-9]` - the second char is any digit but `0` or space
- `[ \d]+` - 1 or more digits or spaces
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Ah brilliant, The demo gives a good breakdown to help understand it too. I never thought about using lookahead for checking length. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with positive lookahead:

```
/^0[1-9](?=\d* \d+$)[ \d]{9,11}$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB1fI9/1)

- `(?=\d* \d+$)` ensures there is at least a space after first characters
- Using `{9,11}` as 2 characters have already been matched at start (zero and non-zero)

Comment: The given requirements implies a space should be allowed as second. Your regex doesn't.

Comment: Questions just says `Must contain exactly 1 space` and that is what my answer is allowing

Comment: Question also says: `second digit not a 0` (not digit part)

Comment: It's a little bit sketchy on the requirements. `Starts with a 0 but second digit not a 0` meant to me that a space could be second. But that would also imply that `0 0...` shouldn't be allowed, since the second **digit** is a `0`. Dunno... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt. It's *slightly* faster than Wiktors. And since the time is already spent, I'll share it.

```
^(?=\d* \d*$)0[1-9 ][\d ]{9,10}$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rE2gG9/1).